# Kenwood dpx u5120 car stereo stuck in standby mode

Tags: audio

Kenwood dpx u5120 car stereo stuck in standby after friend pushing buttons.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Stand by for an answer, Stand by for an answer, stand - - - - - -.

Comment: Have you pressed the reset button?

Answer (score 0):

The following diagram can be found in online versions of the Kenwood dpx u5120 user manual:

[image: Info from helpful link posted in deleted answer]